# Server is not reachable because it was setup as Static IP. Must requires DHCP mode

Tags: linux, networking, router, internet, linux-networking

ISP provides Static IP. Based on MAC address, so that forever the end user have Static IP (to do mail/www servers)

Step 1: So as a user we purchased this module called Static IP using MAC address

Step 2: We bought DELL R310 which has 1 MAC Address and that is our mail/web server remain active/alive about 1 year with the IP 81.82.xxx.2. (configured as Static IP, because purpose is static)

Step 3: Since few days, 81.82.xxx.2 is not traceroute able nor its pingable

Step 4: Question. When ISP supplier promise you will get Static IP for lifetime using MAC Address does that mean, configuration in the server has to be STATIC or Auto DHCP?

Comment: What is this I don't even

Comment: Also, I thought Google would be running a tighter ship, a bit.

Comment: I understand the words, but I have no idea what you just said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Talk to your ISP. We cannot, cannot, help you. Unless someone from your ISP is on here.

Comment: To clarify - the specifics of *your* networking configuration need to be worked out between you and your network provider, probably your ISP or hosting company.

Comment: ...what? If the IP is designated via MAC, it's not static. If it were static, the device assigns the IP itself, and only itself. If it relies on something else to assign the IP in some way, it's not static.

Comment: @Google No, if an IP is assigned based on MAC then the IP would change if you placed a different NIC in the server, meaning it's **not static**. Static means that you have a specific address and it does not change under any circumstances (unless the ISP recalls it, but that's completely different from what you're asking).